# pq.ParquetDataset throws errors as FileNotFoundError

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

For reading data from AWS, when I use `spark.read.parquet("path")`, I can read data, and there is no issue, but for the same path, when I use `pq.ParquetDataset("path").read_pandas()`, it throws errors as `FileNotFoundError`. I also add `import pyarrow.parquet as pq` to use `pq.ParquetDataset`.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Comment: What is `pq.ParquetDataset`? Is it some module/package alias?

Comment: it is a library which I do import pyarrow.parquet as pq

Comment: So how one supposed to know that!  Please add these details to question and update tag as well.

Comment: it is added to it